# Should we use "kelvins" or "kelvin" when referring to temperatures higher than one?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, terminology

Should one say 200 **kelvins** or 200 **kelvin**?

Please provide a source to the answer, as that would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Related on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114079/are-there-reasons-for-the-discrepancies-in-absolute-temp-units-kelvin-vs-kelv).

Comment: I wonder if there's a BrE/AmE divide here. I don't have a source to contradict the two current answers, but during my Physics degree here in the UK I pretty much only heard **kelvin**, without an s

Comment: I suspect people who say "two hundred kelvin" without an S are influenced by Celsius and Fahrenheit where you say "two hundred Celsius" etc (Celsius is considered a scale not a unit). The formal rule expressed in the answers here is to say "kelvins" just like you say "two hundred meters" or "two hundred volts", but people seldom follow rules exactly. Common usage appears to be "two hundred kelvin" even if ISO and NIST demand "kelvins". If you look on Merriam-Webster, none of the examples they give match the rules. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kelvin

Comment: @StuartF even working in physics, hearing the plural is rare (also we'd be more likely to say "Two hundred kay" than use "kelvin" in full)

Answer (score 16):

You should say "two hundred kelvins", and write "200 kelvins" (or "two hundred kelvins") with a small 'k', or "200 K", with a capital 'K'.

The revised SI (November 2018) says

> The **kelvin**, symbol K, is the SI unit of thermodynamic temperature;
> its magnitude is set by fixing the numerical value of the Boltzmann
> constant to be equal to exactly 1.380649 × 10-23...J K-1[joules per
> kelvin]

The US National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) page about this says:

> The kelvin unit is not expressed in degrees like Celsius or Fahrenheit
> are. It is used by itself to describe temperature. For example,
> “mercury loses all electrical resistance at a temperature of 4.2
> **kelvins**.”

[Kelvin: Introduction](https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/kelvin-introduction)

Comment: In German, you should be writing "200 K" (with a thin non-breaking space), not "200 K" (with a normal, breaking space). Is that not the case in English as well? (Note that the lexicographic rules of the International System of Units only talk about "space" without further specifying which kind of space.)

Comment: I can't talk to the size of the space, but there is a space between numerals and units. There is no space between units (eg J/K) or between prefixes and units (eg mJ). There is also no space between numerals and the symbols for degree, minute, and seconds (of angle) 
 https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf

Comment: @JörgWMittag With my US English keyboard layout, I have no idea how I would choose between two different kinds of space. Perhaps academics and scientists know how to do it, and/or they use some kind of typesetting like LaTeX. IMHO that’s not an English language thing, it’s a science-specific thing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the same is true in English scientific text, though a full-width non-breaking space (html \&nbsp; or LaTeX ~) is widely accepted

Comment: @ToddWilcox ctrl+shift+space gives a  non-breaking space in Word etc.

Comment: This may well be what the rules say, but Merriam-Webster quotes Popular Mechanics as repeatedly using singular, in "15 million kelvin" and "95 kelvin". They also offer another example which is even worse: "a temperature of 200 degrees Kelvin" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kelvin

Comment: @StuartF - rules (or, perhaps, conventions) are often ignored, but it is probably sensible for a learner to adhere to them unless there is a very good reason.

Comment: @JörgWMittag English doesn't have a concept of different widths of spaces.  The closest things that it does have are indentation, tabs, and two consecutive spaces between sentences when typing.  (However HTML made double-spaces more complicated than they should be, so you don't always see two spaces between sentences these days.  However it is considered good form when typing a Word document or something, though it can be ignored when handwriting.)

Comment: @Panzercrisis - Typesetting has multiple space widths, and the terminology is part of English.

Comment: Generally the width of a single space is not a part of the grammar though, just a formatting thing.

Comment: @Panzercrisis - yes. Typography is not grammar.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, the unit is "a kelvin", and we pluralize them like any other unit - for example, the [NIST uses **kelvins**](https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/kelvin-introduction) ("mercury loses all electrical resistance at a temperature of 4.2 kelvins") - but it is still often written as "**degrees Kelvin**".

> [The nose temperature of both the pearlite and bainite transformations range from 920 to 980 and 570 to 610 degrees Kelvin for low carbon iron...](https://books.google.com/books?id=HKIrAQAAMAAJ&q=%22degrees%20kelvin%22&dq=%22degrees%20kelvin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVupOpysHwAhWCG80KHVcpDPYQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg)

Comment: it may be often written as "degrees Kelvin", but as that NIST page clearly says, that is wrong usage: _"The kelvin unit is not expressed in degrees like Celsius or Fahrenheit are."_

Comment: I'm always suspicious of NIST pronouncements on SI - for a country that still uses inches they seem to have a lot to say about the rules of SI. Why not look to BIPM? https://www.bipm.org/en/history-si/kelvin

Comment: @DDuck My understanding is that the populace in the USA largely uses Imperial units, but the scientific community uses SI.  Every recent scientific document I've read from the USA is 100% metric.  NIST is a well-respected scientific organisation, although they would certainly spell it *organization*, which actually makes more sense.

Comment: Speaking of not trusting: the official NIST pronunciation guide for "giga" uses the soft "g" (or "j") at the start -> "jiga" (https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/metric-si-prefixes)

Comment: @masher That is definitely a red flag ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5O6F3qwOE

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The US scientific community may *publish* in SI units, but it's remarkable how many times something has a dimension of 0.0254m and similar. (My favorite example of US "metrication" is Boeing's modular designs  for airplane fuselages, which are in sections 8 feet 4 inches long. Well, "100 inches" is "metric", right? :)

Comment: @alephzero Backward compatibility is a thing.

Comment: @masher So that's where Doc Brown got his pronunciation from!

Answer (score 1):

As someone whose training is in condensed matter physics and who has attended a lot of talks, seminars, lectures, etc. in which people talk about temperature dependence, I've only heard "kelvin" without the s. I don't know what the official SI rule is, but "kelvin" is definitely the de facto standard.

---

Edit: I checked a reference I thought might write this out (*An Introduction to Thermal Physics* by Schroeder), and in the one place I could find it he uses "kelvins":

> For this reason it's usually wise to convert temperatures to kelvins before plugging them into any formula.

I stand by my answer in that if you go around saying "kelvins" in spoken language, you may look a little silly.

Comment: Yup.  I'm nowhere near as much into science as that but "kelvins" feels wrong and I think this question is the first time I've ever seen it.  With all temperature scales you plural "degree(s)", not the actual unit.  Same as you have 2 liters of water, not 2 liter of waters.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - as has been already said, a kelvin is a unit, like a metre or a gramme.

Comment: Is it possible that people often say "kelvin", but write "kelvins"?  Often people are more accurate and precise in writing.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'm not sure. I can only recall seeing the unit symbol K in writing, not "kelvin" or "kelvins" written out.

Comment: That's a good point.  It *is* usually just written as "K".  I bet if it was spelled out (not that I would want that!), people would be more likely to say it "properly" when speaking.